# How to correct inline citation order using bibtex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, citing

Is there any way to correct the order of inline citations?

For example if I cite multiple things at once. E.g.

`\cite{McKeithan1995,chan2001,rabinowitz1996}`

Then it might come out as [12,3,16].

Is there anyway to have it so that it would cite in the order that they appear in the bibliography? i.e. as [3,12,16] (even if thats not the order in which they were written inside `\cite{}`)

In my case I'm using `\bibliographystyle{abbrv}`, so my bibliography is in alphabetical order. So i'd like the inline to follow the same ordering.

Thanks!

Comment: `\usepackage[sortcites]{biblatex}`

Comment: @Bobyandbob - Isn't your suggestion rather incomplete? If you want to lead the OP towards using `biblatex` instead of BibTeX, you should provide information about how to go about getting the bibliographic entries formatted in a way that emulates the settings of the `abbrv` bibliography style.

Comment: @Mico. Its just a suggestion. For testing I think we need a MWE.

Comment: You should really provide an MWE, so that we see how you cite in your document and which packages you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you load either the `cite` or the `natbib` citation management package (but not both...). If the `cite` package is loaded, sorting of citation call-outs is enabled automatically unless the `nosort` package option is set. With the `natbib` package, be sure to specify either `sort` or `sort&compress` as one of the package options in order to get, you guessed it, sorting of the numeric-style citation call-outs.